# How do I display default values as blank instead of the type's default value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view model with a couple of properties that are not displaying as desired. One of the properties is of type datetime. The other is an int. In my Create view, the `datetime` appears with a default value of `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` and the `int` has of default of `0`.

We want empty fields by default. How do I do this?

I already found `[DefaultValue("")]` and found it does not address this issue.

Thanks!

ASP.NET MVC 4 RC

Comment: Replace your property types with Nullable types.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try declaring the properties on your ViewModel as nullable using **`?`**

```
public DateTime? DateValue { get; set; }
public int? IntValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks dude it's nice solution, I just forget it all the time :) lol